# Public photo albums & Facebook Graph API

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

It seems that the Facebook graph API can not always pull down the data for *public* albums, even when you provide a valid access token, but you can see these albums through a standard http GET request to facebook.com.

Using the following python code, I am able to GET data from the public album "303027476429477":

```
>>> r = requests.get('https://graph.facebook.com/303027476429477?access_token=MY_SECRET_ACCESS_TOKEN',headers=headers)
>>> r.text
u'{\n   "created_time": "2012-03-11T23:01:28+0000",\n   "name": "Kid Gaga",\n   "id": "303027476429477"\n}'
```

However, for another public album "377622310155", I cannot:

```
>>> r = requests.get('https://graph.facebook.com/377622310155?access_token=MY_SECRET_ACCESS_TOKEN',headers=headers)
>>> r.text
u'{\n   "error": {\n      "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID \'377622310155\' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",\n      "type": "GraphMethodException",\n      "code": 100,\n      "fbtrace_id": "HK87oTbeTs0"\n   }\n}'
```

This seems to be a permissions issue, since if one simply visits *http://facebook.com/377622310155* in their browser, they can see the album does exist (and they didnt need to do any authentication to see it either).

So my question is - what am I doing wrong, and since all i want to do is know if an albumn exists or not, should I just scrape facebook.com's http response?

Comment: You should not scrape Facebook.com because you need written permission from Facebook to do that. The reason could be that the user have turned off Facebook Platform which means that no data of them are available in the API

Comment: I see - thanks for the info :)